# Elasticsearch: search and show results to users, Scroll API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I am confused by the Scroll API at 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

> Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for
>   processing large amounts of data, e.g. in order to reindex the
>   contents of one index into a new index with a different configuration.

What I need is:

1. A user types a search phrase and clicks the search button
2. The program searches Elasticsearch for the first page of results
3. Show the first page of results to the user, and if he clicks "next page" or jumps to another later page, the program displays the results for that page.

The following are two ways that I find:

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch("book")
        .setTypes("children")
        .setQuery(query)
        .setSize(20).execute().actionGet();  

SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch("book")
        .setTypes("children")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
        .setQuery(query)
        .setSize(20).execute().actionGet();
```

Which should I use?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `from` and `size` parameters to control pagination, `from` is the start index, and `size` is the items per page.

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch("book")
    .setTypes("children")
    .setQuery(query)
    .setFrom(20)
    .setSize(20).execute().actionGet();
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: Dan, thanks for your info. I will do what you said. One quick question: I should not setSearchType or setScroll, correct?

Comment: Scan and scroll is not necessary for user search requests, it should be used when you want to process large amounts of data, i.e. re-indexing - so you don't need `setSearchType` or `setScroll`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your confirmation!